Error While Running Addon I Created in SAP B1
I created a simple SAP addon to add an extra tab on the sales order document:
program.cs
using SAPbouiCOM.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SBOAddonProject3
{
    class Program
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Application oApp = null;
                if (args.Length < 1)
                {
                    oApp = new Application();
                }
                else
                {
                    //If you want to use an add-on identifier for the development license, you can specify an add-on identifier string as the second parameter.
                    //oApp = new Application(args[0], "XXXXX");
                    oApp = new Application(args[0]);
                }
                SystemForm MyMenu = new SystemForm();
                oApp.Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        static void SBO_Application_AppEvent(SAPbouiCOM.BoAppEventTypes EventType)
        {
            switch (EventType)
            {
                case SAPbouiCOM.BoAppEventTypes.aet_ShutDown:
                    //Exit Add-On
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
                    break;
                case SAPbouiCOM.BoAppEventTypes.aet_CompanyChanged:
                    break;
                case SAPbouiCOM.BoAppEventTypes.aet_FontChanged:
                    break;
                case SAPbouiCOM.BoAppEventTypes.aet_LanguageChanged:
                    break;
                case SAPbouiCOM.BoAppEventTypes.aet_ServerTerminition:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

menu.cs
using SAPbouiCOM.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SBOAddonProject3
{
    public class SystemForm
    {
        //*****************************************************************
        // At the begining of every UI API project we should first
        // establish connection with a running SBO application.
        // *******************************************************************

        private SAPbouiCOM.Application SBO_Application;

        private SAPbouiCOM.Form oOrderForm;

        private SAPbouiCOM.Item oNewItem;

        private SAPbouiCOM.Item oItem;

        private SAPbouiCOM.Folder oFolderItem;

        private SAPbouiCOM.OptionBtn oOptionBtn;

        private SAPbouiCOM.CheckBox oCheckBox;

        private int i; // to be used as a counter


        private void SetApplication()
        {

            // *******************************************************************
            // Use an SboGuiApi object to establish the connection
            // with the application and return an initialized appliction object
            // *******************************************************************

            SAPbouiCOM.SboGuiApi SboGuiApi = null;
            string sConnectionString = null;

            SboGuiApi = new SAPbouiCOM.SboGuiApi();

            // by following the steps specified above, the following
            // statment should be suficient for either development or run mode

            sConnectionString = System.Convert.ToString(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().GetValue(1));

            // connect to a running SBO Application

            SboGuiApi.Connect(sConnectionString);

            // get an initialized application object

            SBO_Application = SboGuiApi.GetApplication(-1);

        }


        private void AddItemsToOrderForm()
        {

            // add a user data source
            // bear in mind that every item must be connected to a data source

            oOrderForm.DataSources.UserDataSources.Add("OpBtnDS", SAPbouiCOM.BoDataType.dt_SHORT_TEXT, 1);
            oOrderForm.DataSources.UserDataSources.Add("CheckDS1", SAPbouiCOM.BoDataType.dt_SHORT_TEXT, 1);
            oOrderForm.DataSources.UserDataSources.Add("CheckDS2", SAPbouiCOM.BoDataType.dt_SHORT_TEXT, 1);
            oOrderForm.DataSources.UserDataSources.Add("CheckDS3", SAPbouiCOM.BoDataType.dt_SHORT_TEXT, 1);


            //*****************************************
            // Adding Items to the Order form
            // and setting their properties
            //*****************************************


            //***************************
            // Adding Check Box items
            //***************************

            // use an existing item to place youe item on the form
            oItem = oOrderForm.Items.Item("126");

            for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {

                oNewItem = oOrderForm.Items.Add("CheckBox" + i, SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_CHECK_BOX);
                oNewItem.Left = oItem.Left;
                oNewItem.Width = 100;
                oNewItem.Top = oItem.Top + (i - 1) * 19;
                oNewItem.Height = 19;

                // set the Item's Pane Level.
                // this value will determine the Items visibility
                // according to the Form's pane level
                oNewItem.FromPane = 5;
                oNewItem.ToPane = 5;

                oCheckBox = ((SAPbouiCOM.CheckBox)(oNewItem.Specific));

                // set the caption
                oCheckBox.Caption = "Check Box" + i;

                // binding the Check box with a data source
                oCheckBox.DataBind.SetBound(true, "", "CheckDS" + i);

            }

            //****************************
            // Adding Option button items
            //****************************

            // use an existing item to place youe item on the form
            oItem = oOrderForm.Items.Item("44");

            for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {

                oNewItem = oOrderForm.Items.Add("OpBtn" + i, SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_OPTION_BUTTON);
                oNewItem.Left = oItem.Left;
                oNewItem.Width = 100;
                oNewItem.Top = oItem.Top + (i - 1) * 19;
                oNewItem.Height = 19;


                // set the Item's Pane Level.
                // this value will determine the Items visibility
                // according to the Form's pane level
                oNewItem.FromPane = 5;
                oNewItem.ToPane = 5;

                oOptionBtn = ((SAPbouiCOM.OptionBtn)(oNewItem.Specific));

                // set the caption
                oOptionBtn.Caption = "Option Button" + i;

                if (i > 1)
                {
                    oOptionBtn.GroupWith("OpBtn" + ((int)(i - 1)).ToString());
                }

                oOptionBtn.DataBind.SetBound(true, "", "OpBtnDS");
            }
        }

        public SystemForm()
        {


            //*************************************************************
            // set SBO_Application with an initialized application object
            //*************************************************************

            SetApplication();

            //*************************************************************
            // send an "hello world" message
            //*************************************************************

            // SBO_Application.MessageBox("Hello World")

            // events handled by SBO_Application_ItemEvent

            SBO_Application.ItemEvent += new SAPbouiCOM._IApplicationEvents_ItemEventEventHandler(SBO_Application_ItemEvent);
        }

        private void SBO_Application_ItemEvent(string FormUID, ref SAPbouiCOM.ItemEvent pVal, out bool BubbleEvent)
        {

            BubbleEvent = true;

            if (((pVal.FormType == 139 & pVal.EventType != SAPbouiCOM.BoEventTypes.et_FORM_UNLOAD) & (pVal.Before_Action == true)))
            {

                // get the event sending form
                oOrderForm = SBO_Application.Forms.GetFormByTypeAndCount(pVal.FormType, pVal.FormTypeCount);

                if (((pVal.EventType == SAPbouiCOM.BoEventTypes.et_FORM_LOAD) & (pVal.Before_Action == true)))
                {

                    // add a new folder item to the form
                    oNewItem = oOrderForm.Items.Add("UserFolder", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_FOLDER);

                    // use an existing folder item for grouping and setting the
                    // items properties (such as location properties)
                    // use the 'Display Debug Information' option (under 'Tools')
                    // in the application to acquire the UID of the desired folder
                    oItem = oOrderForm.Items.Item("138");


                    oNewItem.Top = oItem.Top;
                    oNewItem.Height = oItem.Height;
                    oNewItem.Width = oItem.Width;
                    oNewItem.Left = oItem.Left + oItem.Width;

                    oFolderItem = ((SAPbouiCOM.Folder)(oNewItem.Specific));

                    oFolderItem.Caption = "User Folder";

                    // group the folder with the desired folder item
                    oFolderItem.GroupWith("138");

                    // add your own items to the form
                    AddItemsToOrderForm();

                    oOrderForm.PaneLevel = 1;

                }

                // If pVal.EventType = SAPbouiCOM.BoEventTypes.et_CLICK And pVal.Before_Action = True Then
                // oOrderForm.PaneLevel = 5

                // End If
                if (pVal.ItemUID == "UserFolder" & pVal.EventType == SAPbouiCOM.BoEventTypes.et_ITEM_PRESSED & pVal.Before_Action == true)
                {

                    // when the new folder is clicked change the form's pane level
                    // by doing so your items will apear on the new folder
                    // assuming they were placed correctly and their pane level
                    // was also set accordingly
                    oOrderForm.PaneLevel = 5;

                }

            }
        }


        private void SBO_Application_AppEvent(SAPbouiCOM.BoAppEventTypes EventType)
        {

            switch (EventType)
            {
                case SAPbouiCOM.BoAppEventTypes.aet_ShutDown:

                    // Take care of terminating your AddOn application

                    SBO_Application.MessageBox("Form Unloaded, Addon will terminate. Terminating 'Order Form Manipulation' Add On...", 1, "Ok", "", "");

                    System.Environment.Exit(0);

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

When I run in visual studio, the addon runs well.
When I package it in Extension Packager, SAP gives the following error when it starts:

I have entered details for SBO 64-bit Client Addon, and selected the exe file in the debug folder generated by Visual Studio.
How can I solve the issue?
